# jqplot meter -> Flot?

Tags: jquery, jqplot, flot

I started using the jqplot library but for implementation reasons, moved on to flot instead.  I found it easier to work with for the data updates I was dealing with.

There was a meter addon for jqplot, and i'd like to get that working again in flot.   Has anyone worked with this before?   I really don't want to distribute this page with 2 different versions of librays that effectively do the same thing.

Basically I need a

```
  jqplot.meterGaugeRenderer.min.js
```

file for flot

Comment: What problems are you having?  Have you tried porting it yourself?  Questions that just ask "can I has the codes" are rarely met with positive responses.  [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I'm more wondering if there's a library out there that I haven't been able to find on my own.  I looked through the google groups and it looks like this was requested 3 years ago but there's no follow up to it.